# Rails 4 - Time-zone settings - invalid error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, cocoon-gem

I'm trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I have an address model which includes an attribute called :time_zone.

The address model is polymorphic. Addresses can belong to organisations or profiles.

I have all of this working where I have profile addresses working (along similar lines to what I'm now trying to achieve with organisation addresses).

I am using cocoon gem for nested attributes.

I have an organisation model and an address model. The associations are:

Organisation.rb

```
has_many :addresses, as: :addressable

accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses,  reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Address.rb

```
belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
```

I have an address_fields form in my address views folder which includes:

```
        <%= f.input :time_zone %>
```

I have an organisations form which has:

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :addresses do |f| %>

              <%= render 'addresses/address_fields', f: f %>
              <% end %>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

               <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an address', f, :addresses, partial: 'addresses/address_fields' %>
```

In my organisations view file, I have:

```
<% if @organisation.addresses.any? %>

    <%= Time.now.in_time_zone(@organisation.addresses.first.time_zone).try(:strftime, '%l.%M %P %Z') %>
```

When I save a form and try to render the time_zone in the organisation show page, I get an error called:

Invalid Timezone:

The error highlights this line of the view code:

```
Time.now.in_time_zone(@organisation.addresses.first.time_zone).try(:strftime, '%l.%M %P %Z') %>
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Well... what value is actually stored in the `time_zone` field?  Is it [one that Rails supports](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html)?

Comment: Just to be sure: you are able to save a form, it is just when re-rendering the saved data you get the error? I do not see where the time-zone is set, so I assume you do not find that relevant? Is it possible the time-zone is nil?